# How do I find out when a stored procedure was last executed in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

Is there any way of finding the last execution time of a stored procedure in Oracle? I have inherited a DB and one of the tables suddenly has millions of duplicates for an end of period total where it usually would only have one row. I think the data is probably inserted by a stored procedure and I want to find when that procedure last executed or what it is that triggers the procedure to run.

I am not a DBA but have quite good SQL skills and so have had this one landed on me whilst the DBA is on leave. I have tried looking at the procedure properties and references but can find no clues. I saw a question that asked about last update and compile times and tried to see if more information was available by selecting all columns as in the code below but with no joy.

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
AND OBJECT_NAME = 'MY_PROC_NAME';
```

In an ideal world I was hoping to find a table showing me the last x executions of stored procedures with execution time and what triggered them.

Comment: There's nothing native to oracle to that does that.  You'd have to "roll your own".  In our shop, all procedures include some standard code that writes to a logging table.  You might check the procedure and see if it does something similar. Lacking that, your only hope would be that AUDIT is set up to capture it, in which case the results would be in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL.

Comment: you could use Log Miner to go through the redo/archive logs...this COULD tell you the user and time when the updates/inserts were ran...could help in your investigative work